# How does the Unix Timestamp work?

Tags: api, unix, timestamp

I'm working on a simple project. The basic idea is that the user can only do something once a day. If I grab the SYSTEMTIME from the device, there is a chance the user will change the time on their phone to exploit the program.

So I don't want to use local/device time.
I looked into Googles API, but it looks like it returns the timezone and requests a timestamp. So that's not what I need.

But I found this website: http://www.convert-unix-time.com/api
This is perfect! But I don't know much about timezones/conversions/unix time/special clock things.

Is this grabbing the time from a server (that the user couldn't possibly alter)? Or is this grabbing the time from my computer and converting it to JSON output? Any additional information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming that altering the code of the program itself is beyond the users' technical capacity? Can you elaborate on the *thing* that the user should only be able to do once per day?

Comment: I'm creating a tutorial for my youtube channel, but I want to make sure I have my facts straight before I create the tutorial. The "thing" is irrelevant. The "thing" can be anything. The "thing" is not related to this question.

For Example:
The user can "spin the wheel" once per day. The user can "vote every 12 hours". The user can "do this" X time. The "thing" is irrelevant. 

The basis for the tutorial is that people are concerned that the user will go into their files and alter the database on a rooted phone, or change the time settings, thus altering their "thing".

Comment: The reason I ask is that if spinning the wheel involves their server, then I was going to suggest moving the at-most-once-daily check entirely to the server instead of worrying about whether the client has access to an accurate wall clock. If you're worries about a user on a rooted phone changing things, it seems like that would include them changing the code that requests the time.